# WebdataGrid And ObjectDatSource - After Filtered Event

Tags: filtering, infragistics, objectdatasource, webdatagrid

I have a webdatagrid which gets bind by the select method of objectdatasource when I click the label.

 
My webdatagrid opens in a panel.

 
Look at the code below for the bind of grid.

```
    ViewState["FromDay"] = FromDay;
    ViewState["ToDay"] = ToDay;


    gv.DataSourceID = objGV.ID;         
    gv.DataBind();


    //get the total no of records
    gv.Behaviors.Paging.Enabled = false;
    lblTotalCount.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["TOTAL_CountROWS"].ToString();            // gv.Rows.Count.ToString();
    gv.Behaviors.Paging.Enabled = true;
    if (ViewState["LNK"] != null && ViewState["LNK"].ToString() == lnkbtn.ID)
    {
        row.Visible = !row.Visible;
    }
```

Now when I filter the webdatagrid and close the panel,and again click the label which binds the webdatagrid, the grid is not getting refreshed.

Please help.

I want to know how to refresh  **DatasourceID**

Comment: Please provide more details on what you mean by "the grid is not getting refreshed".

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try ClearDataSource() method of the grid prior rebind, or just clear the grid's filter rules that have been applied through the Filtering Behavior already.

Hope it helps.
Rado

Comment: Sure I would post the answer soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this creates a filter row, you end up with a row that does not exist in your datasource , your call stack will show you infagistics issues none of us want to get into .  you can remove the filter row when the panel is closed , or make sure the filter row (if present) is not the active row when you load this grid.